# Run CountDownTimer on array of dates

Tags: android, arrays, timer, countdowntimer

I have the array of objects that look like this:

```
public class Time {

    public String start_time;

    public String finish_time;

    public Time(String start_time, String finish_time) {
        this.start_time = start_time;
        this.finish_time = finish_time;
    }
}
```

I need to implement a timer in my Fragment in the following way:

it should start counting down from the first element in array in a way that on one single `Time` element it should first start counting down to the time left to reach `start_time`, then when the timer reaches `start_time`, it should start counting down to `finish_time` and, eventually, when it reaches `finish_time` it should do the same previous actions for the next element in the array. And when the whole array is finished, it should display 00:00:00.

PS: start_time and finish_time are formatted like this: `HH:mm` however the timer should be `HH:mm:ss`

Can anybody help with implementing that or at least give an idea?

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: I haven't come up with an idea for implementing the timer yet. That's why I'm asking here.
I think I should create a separate class that extends CountDownTimer and do something with onFinish method, but still no ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found the appropriate answer. Thanks a lot to the guy who helped me with it:

class Clazz {

```
private Timer dateTimer;

private Timer remainderTimer;

private Date nextDate;

private boolean remainderTimerStarted;

private static final long REMINDER_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;

private static final String[] DATES = { "12.04.2015 22:21", "12.04.2015 22:22", "12.04.2015 22:23" };

private int currentIndex;

public Clazz() {
    dateTimer = new Timer();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Clazz instance = new Clazz();
    instance.run();
}

private void run() {
    nextDate = parseDate(DATES[currentIndex]);
    schedule();
}

public void schedule() {
    runSecondsCounter();
    dateTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("Current date is:" + new Date());
            currentIndex++;
            if (currentIndex < DATES.length) {
                nextDate = parseDate(DATES[currentIndex]);
                System.out.println("Next date is:" + nextDate);
                schedule();
            } else {
                remainderTimer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, nextDate);

}

private Date parseDate(String nextDate) {
    Date date = null;
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm",
            Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        date = format.parse(nextDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}

private void runSecondsCounter() {
    if (remainderTimerStarted) {
        remainderTimer.cancel();
    }

    remainderTimer = new Timer();
    remainderTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            remainderTimerStarted = true;
            long remains = nextDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println("Remains: " + (remains / 1000) + " seconds");
        }
    }, REMINDER_UPDATE_INTERVAL, REMINDER_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
}
```

}